# Different HTTP StatusCodes between IIS versions

Tags: asp.net, api, iis

I am writing some fuzz tests for my Web API and I am experiencing some differences in the HTTP return codes between IIS 8.5 and IIS 10.0. I have the following method in my API:

```
[Route("{id:int}/GetSomething")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSomething(int id)
{
    return Ok(2);
}
```

This gives the API call

```
http://server/api/Something/5/GetSomething
```

which works well.

During fuzz testing, I try different random inputs to the API, such as a string instead of an int:

```
http://server/api/Something/asdf/GetSomething
```

When I host my API on IIS Express 10.0, the StatusCode is "404 Not Found".
When I host my API on IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2, the StatusCode is "401 Unauthorized".

When I try to insert a blank space:

```
http://server/api/Something/ /GetSomething
```

both servers return "404 Not Found".

**Why do they behave differently for the string input? Is there a way to configure either one to behave like the other?**

Comment: I would think you get different status code because the two version of IIS run the two sites in different securitycontext. Check the IIS 8.5's application pool user.

Comment: What authentication method do you use? Windows authentication has its famous loopback issue and that leads to 401.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Web API and IIS @AllanS.Hansen , can you provide some more information about what I should look for? IIS 8.5 runs my site under "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: I am using claims based authentication @LexLi. I don't think Windows Authentication is the issue here.

Comment: I'd start here and see if some of the things mentioned will help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful link @AllanS.Hansen. I think that security context is the root of this issue, but I have not been able to change the behaviour of IIS v8.5 by changing the application pool user to a user with administrative rights. However, I posted the question out of curiosity, so I wil not spend any more time investigating it. I will just rephrase my tests so they pass regardless of IIS version.